# Python unittest. Заменить 1 объект другим на время тестов

Tags: python, python-unittest

Как правильно заменить на время тестов объект `my_bot`  (экземпляр класса `Bot`)  на объект `mockbot`  (экземпляр класса Mockbot) ?

Пояснение что-бы избежать XY вопроса:

Во время теста у меня есть объект `mockbot`, который при входящих запросах передается в обработчики.

Внутри обаботчиков создаются экземпляры разных классов (например "reg_user"), которые выполняют всю логику. При исполнении логики классы импортируют и используют настоящего бота, от чего тесты падают.
Конечно можно передавать параметр `mockbot` при создании экземпляра, но это похоже на кастыль, т.к. это всегда 1 и тот-же бот.

Код:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from postconfig import bot as my_bot
from ptbtest import Mockbot


@patch(my_bot, mockbot)  # mockbot not exists here yet
class TestConversation(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mockbot = Mockbot()
```

Дополнительный нюанс в том, что mockbot определяется только в функции setUp.

Я пробовал поиграться с аргументами (попеременно делая их строками, а не объектами, но всегда выдаются разные ошибки в связи с неправильным типом.
Складывается ощущение, что я неправильно использую `patch` и он не подменяет 2 объекта, а заменяет на дефолтную пустышку (`mock`).

P.S. я гуглил и читал доки, но все равно не понятно.
https://pastebin.com/22Zwv239

Comment: *"но это похоже на кастыль"* - нет, на костыль похожа попытка что-то заменять во время тестами левыми способами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы совсем неправильно используете `patch`. Вот рабочий пример. Тут три файла в одном каталоге:

- bot.py - собственно модуль с определением бота
- bot_client.py - модуль использующий бот
- test_bot_client.py - тесты модуля `bot_client`

```
# bot.py
class Bot:
    def send(self):
        print('in bot')
        return 'bot result'

bot = Bot()
```

```
# bot_client.py
from bot import bot

def use_bot():
    return bot.send()
```

```
# test_bot_client.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from bot_client import use_bot

class MockedBot:
    def send(self):
        print('in mocked bot')
        return 'mocked bot result'

class BotClientTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mocked_bot = MockedBot()
        self.patcher = patch('bot_client.bot', self.mocked_bot)
        self.patcher.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patcher.stop()

    def test_bot_client(self):
        result = use_bot()
        self.assertEqual(result, 'mocked bot result')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Самое важное и неочевидное в использовании mock-ов в питоне, когда необходимо заменить зависимость, это **место** где нужно использовать `patch`. Его нужно использовать не в месте определения объекта, который мы хотим замокать, а в месте, в котором мы этот объект используем.

То есть в данном примере, мы пишем тест для клиента бота и хотим бот замокать. Для этого нам нужно мокать именно переменную в модуле клиента, т.е. `bot` из `bot_client.py`, тот который там появился в результате импорта.

Причина этого проста. Если мы будет пытаться замокать именно `bot` из `bot.py`, то у нас ничего не выйдет, так как в момент, когда мы это делаем (т.е. в `setUp` методе теста), импорт `bot` в `bot_client.py` уже произошел (это случилось, когда мы в тесте делали импорт `bot_client.use_bot`, а модуль `bot_client` в свою очередь импортировал `bot.bot`) и замена `bot` в модуле `bot` уже нечего не дает (в `bot_client` переменная `bot` содержит оригинальное значение и наша замена переменно в `bot` никак на это не влияет).

Comment: Спасибо, работает!
Кучу инфы перелопатил, и везде копипаста о том что это, но 0 упоминания реальных юзкейсов.
Я думал там совсем черая магия, вроде модификации AST или импортов.
В отчаяньи уже хотел переписывать на `pytest` :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй навесить patch на конкретный тесткейс или запатчить в setUp
и надо указывать полный путь до my_bot

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from postconfig import bot as my_bot
from ptbtest import Mockbot


class TestConversation(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mockbot = @patch("postconfig.my_bot") # здесь надо указать полный путь
        self.mockbot.return_value = MockBot()
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработало. https://pastebin.com/22Zwv239

Comment: зачем ты хочешь вообще бота замокать? тестировать функционал библиотеки нет смысла, а так лучше раздели логику приложения от интерфейсов бота так, чтоб ты мог без привязки к боту тестировать свою логику

Comment: А как это сделать? Я не такой спец в логике :)
Цепочка из нескольких методов бота у меня помещена в модуль "классы" с соответствующмими именами (например "показать профиль", что является для бота отправкой нескольких сообщений + crud и т.п.)
У меня в обработчиках только минимальная логика, а так все является методами класса (`User` например) в основном.
Я не вижу смысла переносить абсолютно все вызовы бота из обработчиков в классы, т.к. обработчики в любом случае получают бота в параметрах (замоканного во время тестов).